# Convergence of a sequence given $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^2(a_{n+1}-a_n)=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^2(a_{n+1}-a_n)=1$$
I want to show $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going to ask this question but figured it out as I was writing down my attempt, so might as well post the proof:

I want to use the Cauchy Criterion for convergence since we have w.l.o.g. for $m>n$
$$|a_m-a_n|\leq |a_m-a_{m-1}|+\cdots+|a_{n+1}-a_n|=\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}|a_{i+1}-a_i|$$

Now, by limit comparison test, $\sum_{i=n}^\infty|a_{i+1}-a_i|$ and $\sum_{i=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}$ both converge. So by setting $N$ appropriately big enough and $n\geq N$,
$$\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}|a_{i+1}-a_i|\leq \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}|a_{i+1}-a_i|<\epsilon.$$